# FIVE time press home button in iphone and get current location?

Tags: ios, iphone

FIVE time press home button in iphone and get a current location coordinate and post to apis server this task possible or not ?

Comment: Do you mean like pressing the home button 5 times in a row or do you really mean 5 times coming back to the app? You can't do the first, you can do the second.

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle home button events in your app : you can only  know when it becomes inactive or active using your app delegate methods : `applicationWillResignActive` `applicationDidEnterBackground` or `applicationWillTerminate`

Read  [UIApplicationDelegate protocol reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html) for further information